# Am I understanding the logic behind 2d Java char arrays correctly?

Tags: java, 2d

I'm working on a word search project. I need to make sure i'm not totally losing my mind. Do i understand the logic behind 2d arrays correctly? If i make a 3x3 grid, i would enter the data via 2d char array like this correct?

```
    ([0][0])([0][1])([0][2])
    ([1][0])([1][1])([1][2])
    ([2][0])([2][1])([2][2])
```

I know this is very simple. I'm not trying to make a joke. I got really into the project and had a momentary lapse in memory.

Comment: Yes, you could represent a grid using a 2d array as you've indicated.

Comment: Pretty much. But to get things correct: the way you think of it here, apparently, with the grid is a pretty nice model for the matrix, but in reality there exists no such thing as "rows" and "columns" in 2d-arrays. It's just two dimensions. You can of course use the model, but be sure not to mix it up with what really happens inside the machine.

Comment: thank you sir you have saved my tenuous grasp on sanity.

Comment: This is a weird question.